# linear actuator internal resistors

Tags: resistors, actuator

I have been trying for nearly a week now to try and build a mechanically locking box. I thought I could try using a linear actuator to do this, so I found a [model I liked](https://www.firgelliauto.com/products/mini-rod-actuator).

My question is as follows:

Do linears actuators have built in resistors to limit the current? This linear actuator model tells me it has a 2.5A current rating but it does not specify whether or not it is limited internally.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.5A is the load at 100% of rated force- during starting and if you overload it, it will draw more than that. Note that the duty cycle is only 25% at full load. If you run it for 30 seconds, say, you have to let it rest for 90 seconds before operating it again.

The current drawn (after initial start-up) will be roughly proportional to the load. So for a lighter load, it will draw less current (though never quite zero because of friction and other losses), and it will draw the maximum when stalled (not a good idea). In a sense then you do control the maximum current to the extent you limit the force the actuator must produce. Since it has limits switches built-in, you don't need to worry about stalling it at the end positions.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. That is exactly what I was looking for.